# Fetch object id with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": 97,
    "name": "Jon",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Messageria"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "name": "Doe",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Javascript"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 99,
    "name": "Mark",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "PHP"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Laravel"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How could I filter this array and return only developers who have, for example, technology with id 6?
The return I need is only developers who have a relationship with technology id 6, however I need other related technologies to also appear to the developer.

I know that through the find method it is possible to do this, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
const result = developers.find(dev => dev.technologies ?);
```

What would be the correct form?

Comment: [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) array operations for this task. Something like this:

```
persons.filter(person => person.technologies.some(tech => tech.id == 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return details of person with technology id 6:

```
persons = [
  {
    "id": 97,
    "name": "Jon",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Messageria"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "name": "Doe",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Javascript"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 99,
    "name": "Mark",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "PHP"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Laravel"
      }
    ]
  }
]

persons.filter(person => person.technologies.find(tech => tech.id == 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for finding whether element exist with specific id or not:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 97,
    "name": "Jon",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Messageria"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "name": "Doe",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Javascript"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 99,
    "name": "Mark",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "PHP"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Laravel"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const myFilteredData = data.filter(test => test.technologies.some(data => data.id===6));

console.log(
myFilteredData
)
```